# How to handle certain events with a single class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How do I make a class that for example, handles all startDrag() and stopDrag() events? There is no MovieClip for this class. I want this class to function solely as a handler for events that are used by multiple classes.

I'm making a game and I have lots of items that can be dragged and dropped, and I need a more efficient way rather than putting this code in every single item class.

So is there any other way of doing this? Right now I have to copy and paste this into every class I have that can be dragged and dropped.

```
public function Weapon1() 
{
        originalPosition = new Point(x,y);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEntrance);
}
public function onEntrance(evt:Event)
{
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
}
public function mousedown(evt:MouseEvent)
{
        startDrag(true);
}
public function mouseup(evt:MouseEvent)
{
        stopDrag();
        if(dropTarget)
        {
            if(dropTarget.parent.name == "slot")
            {
                this.x = dropTarget.parent.x;
                this.y = dropTarget.parent.y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnToPosition();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnToNewPosition();
    }
}
public function returnToPosition()
{
    x = originalPosition.x;
    y = originalPosition.y;
}
public function returnToNewPosition()
{
    x = newPosition.x;
    y = newPosition.y;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is **Inheritance** which is one of [the four fundamental concepts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html) of **object-oriented programming**. In OOP, inheritance enables classes to take on the properties and methods of an existing base class (also called a super class).

So; You should create a base class with drag and drop logic and extend that class to create your other derived classes (also called sub-classes).

For example, here is the base class (`Draggable`):

```as3
package
{
    public class Draggable extends MovieClip
    {
        //Constructor

        public function Draggable()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStageReady);
        }

        //Event Handlers

        protected function onStageReady(event:Event):void
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
        }

        protected function mousedown(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            startDrag(true);
            //more stuff here...
        }

        protected function mouseup(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stopDrag();
            //more stuff here...
        }
    }
}
```

...and here is the `Weapon1` class that extends the base class:

```as3
package
{
    public class Weapon1 extends Draggable
    {
        //Constructor

        public function Weapon1()
        {
            //initialize Weapon1
        }

        //Methods, handlers, etc...
    }
}
```

As you see; it's the **`extend`** keyword that enables inheritance for the `Weapon1` class.
You can go on creating more weapon classes...

```as3
public class Weapon2 extends Draggable { ... }
public class Weapon3 extends Draggable { ... }
public class Weapon4 extends Draggable { ... }
```

Notice that the `Draggable` class also **extends** the `MovieClip` class to gain some other functionality. So, each class you extend from `Draggable` will have the functionality of both the `MovieClip` and `Draggable` classes.

#### References:

- **[Object Oriented Programming](http://oreilly.com/actionscript/excerpts/actionscript-3-design-patterns/object-oriented-programming.html)**
- **[Inheritance](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html)**
- **[Encapsulation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/encapsulation.html)**
- **[Abstraction](http://www.as3dp.com/2011/05/beginning-actionscript-3-0-abstraction-the-factory-method-at-work/)**
- **[Polymorphism](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/polymorphism-and-interfaces.html)**